# Стоит ли убирать отметку ответа решением при обновлении вопроса?

Tags: поддержка, правки, принятые-ответы

Однажды я писал код и столкнулся с проблемой. Я подробно ее описал и вскоре получил подходящий ответ. Но через некоторое время я решил этот код переписать и столкнулся со смежной проблемой из той же отрасли, но которой раньше не было. Я решил поправить свой старый вопрос (потому что они очень схожи, просто Update более специфичен) вместо того, чтобы создавать новый. И теперь так получается, что ответ, который я до этого отметил решением, больше как бы не является решением (на новую часть вопроса, однако вполне подходит для старой). Что следует делать в таких ситуациях? Если оставить отметку решения, то потенциальные ответчики могут решить, что вопрос уже решен и не будут даже его просматривать. Но ведь и тот человек, который дал ответ в свое время проблему решил и тоже заслуживает поощрения? Возможно мне вообще стоило создать отдельный вопрос в этом случае? Прошу подсказать, чтобы знать, что делать, если в будущем снова столкнусь с подобной ситуацией. Спасибо.

Сам вопрос: [Как в JavaScript нужно правильно деинициализировать объект?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586479/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-javascript-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)

Comment: Как мне кажется, популярная ситуация, очень тесто пересекающаяся с переводом обсуждения в комментарии к принятому ответу.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Я решил поправить свой старый вопрос (потому что они очень схожи, просто Update более специфичен) вместо того, чтобы создавать новый

От этого все проблемы. Если поменять вопрос, ответы становятся бессмысленными. Сейчас рекомендую сделать так:

1. Откатите старый вопрос к первоначальному состоянию.
2. Как вы правильно догадались, задайте новый вопрос. Если для его понимания будет полезен старый, можно дать ссылку.

Вообще, вопросы же бесплатно задаются, зачем их экономить? :)

Comment: Боязнь получить по башке за дубликат делает свое дело. Спасибо за наводку, именно так и поступлю.

Comment: @smellyshovel нее, не нужно бояться. Если ответы потеряли смысл или стали неверными, то это не дубликат. Вот если все те же самые ответы отвечают и на новый вопрос — тогда дубликат. :)

Comment: @smellyshovel, дубликаты это не плохо. Плохо когда после обновления вопроса все ответы становятся неактуальными

Comment: @Grundy буду иметь в виду.

Comment: Нам нужен дубликат @Grundy.

Comment: @alexolut, на мете я не могу дубликатить :)

Comment: @smellyshovel "по башке" получает только гвоздь в табличке, указывающей на такой же вопрос. Бывает, что проблема встречается в разных видах, но имеет одно и то же решение при этом, поэтому закрытие как "дубликат" несколько особняком от прочих причин: это просто "перенаправление" без негативного подтекста. В общем случае, по крайней мере.

Comment: @D-side в любом случае вопросы, требующие перенаправления, не особо несут пользу.

Comment: @smellyshovel ошибаетесь. Они позволяют найти набор решений, подходящих к нескольким разным проблемам. Но поскольку все эти проблемы в один вопрос запихивать неудобно и неправильно (это подстройка вопроса под ответы), используется такой вот механизм.

Comment: @D-side мы точно об одном и том же говорим? Как они могут позволять найти какие-то решения, если они, по сути, закрываются?

Comment: @smellyshovel не удаляются же. А значит, могут быть найдены.

Comment: @D-side если речь идет о выдаче в поисковых движках, то тогда, конечно, согласен.

Comment: @smellyshovel да, поисковики индексируют в том числе вопросы, закрытые как дубликаты.